# Unable to access form variables in ASP.NET on submitting form

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am unable to access request form variable. Given below is the snippet of my aspx code.

```
<form id="mainmasterform" runat="server">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><label for="ownfname">First Name</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox id="ownfname" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="ownlname">Last Name</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox id="ownlname" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Button ID="submitowner" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="modifyDetails" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Now onclick of button calls a server method "modifyDetails" which tries to access form variables using Request.Form object.

```
protected void modifyDetails(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string fname = Request.Form["ownfname"];
    string lname = Request.Form["ownlname"];
}
```

It does not work, the strings fname and lname are always null.
Please help as I am not able to understand what is wrong over here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do the following?

```
protected void modifyDetails(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string fname = ownfname.Text;
    string lname = ownlname.Text;
}
```

That's how ASP.NET is designed to work.

Comment: After applying your given code it started working.
But unable to understand when to use Request.Form["Something"] and "Something.Text" ? Can anyone explain

Comment: Under normal circumstances, you would never use `Request.Form["Something"]` in ASP.NET. ASP.NET is designed to reference post values using the syntax I've posted above.

Comment: using 
    string fname = ownfname.Text gives me values, but it gives me old values. As for example when the web page is rendered text within "ownfname" is "Robert" and then you modify it to "David" then click on submit button. After submitting accessing the "ownfname.Text" property still gives "Robert" and not "David". I am creating a modify data form. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: This is a completely separate issue and one that has never, ever happened to me. There must be something strange about your page. I suggest you start a new question. Be sure to include a little code so that people can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Either don't use the `<asp:` controls (instead use regular HTML Controls), or set their `ClientIDMode` property to static. [Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string fname = ownfname.Text
string lname = ownlname.Text
```